# Конвертировать MS-DOS time format

Tags: c#, c, windows, hex

Нужно конвертировать байты MS-DOS time полученные с устройства 17 86 FF 4C в обычный читаемый формат. Пробовал таблицу http://www.vsft.com/hal/dostime.htm , но не получилось.

Comment: А как именно получены эти данные? С какого устройства? Почему вы решили, что это данные именно в указанном формате?

Comment: Мануал гласит  MS-DOS time format, with high-order bytes for date and low-order bytes for time.  Length (byte) 4

Comment: определитесь, вам C# или С реализация нужна?

Comment: Ну вообще лучше на С

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по тому, что вы написали, можо так (в Windows, и исходя из получения начиная с младшего байта):

```
int main() {
    FILETIME ft;

    if (DosDateTimeToFileTime(0x4CFF, 0x8617, &ft) == 0) {
        puts("DosDateTimeToFileTime Error!\n");
        return 0;
        }

    SYSTEMTIME st;

    if (FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st) == 0) {
        puts("FileTimeToSystemTime Error!\n");
        return 0;
        }

    printf("%02d.%02d.%04d  %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
           st.wDay, st.wMonth, st.wYear,
           st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond);
    }
```

Получается

```
31.07.2018  16:48:46
```